# Flask Blueprint application - How to get application context within mqtt on_message callback

Tags: python, flask

I have created a flask application using Blueprints. 
This application receives data via paho.mqtt.client. 
This is also the trigger to processes the data and run processes afterwards.

'system' is a blueprint containing mqtt.py and functions.py

- functions.py contains the function to process the data once received
- mqtt.py contains the definition of the mqtt client

mqtt.py

```
from app.system import functions
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
#....

def on_message(mqttc,obj,msg):   
    try:
        data = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
        # start main process
        functions.process(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("error: ", e)
        pass
```

Once I receive data and the on_message callback is triggered I get an out of application context error:

error:  Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.

How can i get the application context within the on_message callback?
I tried importing current_app and using something like this

```
from flask import current_app
#...
def on_message(mqttc,obj,msg):   
    try:
        data = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
        app = current_app._get_current_object()
        with app.app_context():
            # start main process
            functions.process(data)
```

I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

There is this package - https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - that might help, but it only works with one worker instance.

Most of the time you set the application context when you create the `app` object.
So wherever you create your app is where you should initialize the extension. In your case it sounds like `functions.py` needs `mqtt.py` to carry out its logic, so you should initialize your `mqtt` client in your application creation.

From the flask docs - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/

> If you see that error while configuring your application, such as when
>   initializing an extension, you can push a context manually since you
>   have direct access to the app. Use app_context() in a with block, and
>   everything that runs in the block will have access to current_app.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    with app.app_context():
        #init_db()
        initialize mqtt client

    return app
```

Comment: I am sure the flask-mqtt will resolve the problem if you do need only one client. I need 2 mqtt clients however and they need both different config app.config['MQTT_USERNAME'] and app.config['MQTT_PASSWORD']